# What's the limit of google transliteration?

Tags: api, transliteration

I've used google transliteration API experimentally. It's working fine and I've noticed that it allows only five words at a time. Is there any method to send more words? and is there any daily limit? If I have 100 words, I will have to send a set of five and then join them?

Answer (score 0):

100k characters per day for ver 2.
The developer console allows you to apply for higher limits (may cost money depending on your needs?) https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Looks like ther is a method for making more than jut individual words transliteratable: https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started#makeTransliteratable